# Next & Closing Buttons

Tags: fancybox

First timer here!

Fancybox is just what I need, amazing.

I have set it up on one of my web pages but I can't get the next arrows or any buttons to go.

I have a temp page set up at www.burnmoorcc.org.uk/2bfit/index.html and the image is bottom left under gallery.

Also incidentally the page has for some reason moved to the left!

Thank you for any help,

Best wishes
Graeme